# Changing date format with xslt string functions

Tags: string, date, xslt, substring

I have to solve something with XSLT and am at a loss. I think I need the string-length function, some chose tests, and substring, but I don’t know. The problem is relatively simple.

My xml looks like the sample below. However, I have used YYYY, MM, and DD to represent numbers in the dates.

```
<date normal=”YYYMMDD”> Month, DD, YYYY</date>
<date normal=”YYYY/YYYY”> YYYY-YYYY</date>
<date normal=”YYYYMM”> Month, YYYY</date>
<date normal=”YYYYMM>MM-YYYY</date>
<name normal=”Smith, John”> John Smith </name>
```

I need to print all the elements as they are, except for JUST the two elements that have attributes `normal=”YYYYMM”`. They need to be printed but with attributes in the form `normal=YYYY-MM`

I cannot rely on the material in the element as it tends to be in a variety of different formats as it is free text.

I keep trying to use string-length function to identify attribute values with 6 characters in the element date. But then I can’t figure out how to split the string in the output with the hyphen. I am guessing it uses one of the substring functions, but I can’t get everything to work together.

Thanks for any advice you can give,
Christine

Comment: I assume you are using XSLT 1.0, because with 2.0 the task would be trivial. But if you're constrained to an old version of XSLT, you should really say so in the question, to avoid misunderstandings.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?:

```
<xsl:choose>
  <xsl:when text="string-length(@normal) = 6 and number(@normal) = number(@normal)">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(substring(@normal, 1, 4), '-', substring(@normal, 5, 2))" />
  </xsl:when>
  <xsl:otherwise>
    <xsl:value-of select="@normal" />
  </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

The `number(@normal) = number(@normal)` check ensures that `@normal` is a number, since it looks like you also have some non-date values in the `normal` attribute.  Is there any risk that it might be a 6-digit non-date number?

Comment: Hi, yes, I shouldn't have a six digit non-date number, and will never have it in the date element. I could limit the chose to normal attributes of only the date element. Or

Comment: Perhaps you could show us some of your XSL and a more complete view of the XML so I could tell you where the above would fit into the big picture.

Comment: let me try out the code that you gave me and then I will get back if I am still in difficulties. I think the test and the concat function should do the trick. I didn't think of using a number test, but that should solve the issue. I can also try just adding in to the test `<xsl:when text="string-length(date[@normal]) = 6 and number(@normal) = number(@normal)">` Does that seem right? adding in the xpath for the test?

Comment: The answer depends somewhat on the context in which the XSL is executing, but assuming that you are in the context of a `date`, `name`, etc. (i.e. the direct parent of a `@normal` attribute), this test should work to only modify `normal`s that have `date` parents: `<xsl:when text="string-length(@normal[../date]) = 6 and number(@normal) = number(@normal)">`

Comment: Thanks, I really should have been able to figure that out. I am really not good at all with xslt functions as I am usually just simply converting xml to html. so when I have to do this more complicated stuff, I run into difficulties. The context you described is right, I am just talking about direct parent date elements. Thank you again, and I will reply back here when I get things to work, which I am sure I will with the help you gave.

Answer (score 0):

**This complete and short transformation:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="@normal[string-length()=6]">
  <xsl:attribute name="normal">
   <xsl:value-of select="concat(substring(.,1,4),'-',substring(.,5))"/>
  </xsl:attribute>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the following XML document (the provided fragment wrapped into a single top element):**

```
<t>
    <date normal="YYYMMDD"> Month, DD, YYYY</date>
    <date normal="YYYY/YYYY"> YYYY-YYYY</date>
    <date normal="YYYYMM"> Month, YYYY</date>
    <date normal="YYYYMM">MM-YYYY</date>
    <name normal="Smith, John"> John Smith </name>
</t>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result:**

```
<t>
   <date normal="YYYMMDD"> Month, DD, YYYY</date>
   <date normal="YYYY/YYYY"> YYYY-YYYY</date>
   <date normal="YYYY-MM"> Month, YYYY</date>
   <date normal="YYYY-MM">MM-YYYY</date>
   <name normal="Smith, John"> John Smith </name>
</t>
```